# Bind to multiple parameters without using a view model

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

If I'm posting some variables to a Web API method, is it possible to do this without creating a view model?

It seems that you can only bind to a single parameter (which represents the request's body), so if there are multiple variables then that necessitates a view model to contain them.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one param decorated with `[FromBody]`, so therefore that one param must encapsulate all the data coming from the request body.

Comment: That seems inefficient.

Comment: Quite the opposite, in fact. Using multiple params, you just have a loose collection of unrelated data with no validation. With a view model, you have a defined contract, a cohesive set of data, and you can apply validation to ensure that that data is well-formed.

Comment: A method's parameter list isn't a loose collection of unrelated data. Good point about validation though.

Comment: Unrelated in the sense of independent. It may have meaning to *you*, but it ends there. The members of a class define the very identity of that class, and thus work together to form a full picture. Not so with params.

Comment: The parameters of a method (along with the return type) define the identity of a method. It's a method name instead of a class name and, around the data, it's parentheses instead of curly brackets.